# Media volume is changed when on a phone call

Tags: settings, calls, volume-control, mute

I'm using Android Pie on a Samsung Galaxy S9 phone.

I noticed if I set the media volume down all the way to mute it that the volume is turned up a bit only while on a call.

If anyone is experiencing this issue, it would be appreciated if you can tell me if there are any settings I can access to stop Android from adjusting the media volume while on a call taking it out of mute mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a different volume bar for when you are on a call. I think the easiest way to set this is to change the volume whilst on a call, this will save the settings for the next time you're on a call. If you want to change the settings before you go on a call just phone someone yourself and change the settings, they don't even have to pick up for you to do so.

This is of course not ideal and I'll change the answer if I find a app or so that can do this.

You can not however mute the sound from a phone call.